# programtical zoom in MKMapView stops before doubletap .. why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, zooming

So I am trying to implement a zoom in on an MKMapView for IOS... using the following code, and it works...to a point... after the zoom gets to a certain level, this method stops zooming... even though direct double tap on the map will allow at least 2 more zooms...

So, the questions I have are.. #1 why does this stop working?  #2 is there something I can do to fix it so I can zoom just as far in with this method as I can with double tap...and #3 if not, how can I trigger the double tap gesture in an MKMapView programatically and just call that built in method instead of this attempt at a custom zoom?

```
            MKCoordinateRegion region;                
            MKCoordinateSpan span; 
            region.center=mapView.region.center;

            span.latitudeDelta=mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta /2.0002;
            span.longitudeDelta=mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta /2.0002;
            region.span=span;
            [mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
```

Comment: Can you include the code where you define `region`?

Comment: Edited above, its just a declaration.